# Worth to initialize a variable to store a value, in order to avoid multiple value request from a singleton's property

Tags: c#, initialization, singleton

I have a singleton where I store multiple values, that need to be accessed from the application.

```
internal sealed class Foo
{
    private static readonly Foo instance = new Foo();
    public static Foo Instance { get { return instance; } }

    public Size RandomSize { get; set; }
    // ...

    static Foo() { }
    private Foo() { }
}
```

My question is that when I need to access the values of e.g. `RandomSize` often, let's assume 10 times in one method, is it worth to initialize a new `Size` variable as a copy of just the values of `RandomSize`? So I can avoid to request the value of the singleton multiple times. Or is the trade-off bad due to occupying some memory and having the cost of creating a new object?

```
Size tempSize = Foo.Instance.RandomSize;
```

Comment: Why don't you just measure the performance? And, is `Size` a struct or a class?

Comment: Why do you want to "avoid to request the value of the singleton multiple times"? What benefit do you think will this "avoiding" might bring? Just do what is most naturally correct. When you have a correctly functioning bit of code, **if** it's not performing then *measure your code* in a profiler and decide what needs optimizing. Making pre-emptive optimizations of this kind is (more-often-than-not) unnecessary and leads to code that is hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: Simply try it out by measuring. No-one here can give a a valuable answer, because it just deends on so many factors, which can´t be covered in a single answer.

Comment: @Adrian It's the default .NET `Size`, so it's a struct.

Comment: if it's a struct, then calling the constructor to copy it is unnecessary. Just use `=`. structs are value types.

Comment: @spender It was a thought that it might be more performant. Moreover the code is nicer to read without the 'long' term I need to write to access the singleton's value.

Comment: @Adrian Ah yes I forgot that when I wrote the sample. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @L.Guthardt "nicer to read" should win every time unless you prove that there's an important need for a faster but harder-to-follow way of doing things.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ok, thank you. I guess I'll try out to measure performance. I was just wondering about that the past few days, because this szenario appeared quite often.

Comment: @spender Ok, thanks. So I go with that solution. So you agree that it is legit to create a new field 'just' for that?

Comment: what do you mean by field? i think you mean "local variable". a field is a variable that belongs to a class.

Comment: @Adrian Sorry, I misused the term "field". I meant a basic local variable.